# relative pronoun and preposition

Tags: grammaticality

I'm wondering if 'This is the bus for which i waited ' is correct.

If  "for" should be located only after the verb, 'waited', can u plz explain why?

In my understanding, only phrasal verb should be put together and "wait for"is not a phrasal verb but preposition,meaning it can be positioned before which.

Is there any book i can get some reference?

Comment: Are you asking whether prepositional phrases can immediately follow non-phrasal verbs? (That would "put together" the verb and the preposition.) The answer is yes: *I waited for the bus*.

Comment: @deadrat Alice J wants support for separating "waited" and "for", as in the example sentence.

Comment: @MetaEd I was confused by "only phrasal verb should be put together".

Answer (score 1):

["To wait for" can be a phrasal verb.](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/wait-for-sb)  As a native English speaker, I would say

> This is the bus [that] I waited for.

(I would usually omit the word "that," but it is understood).

Your original sentence is also a correct way to phrase it, but it sounds very formal.